# How to use pspg for mycli pager

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf, dbclient

I have this config on my `.myclirc`

```
table_format = psql
enable_pager = True
```

This the output is not what I expeceted, I tried to set pspg on the `[client]` section on the `.my.cnf` but `mysqldump` will complain about.

```
[client]
pager = pspg -X --quit-if-one-screen
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer in [github](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli/issues/1003#issuecomment-921153161) works great.

In my `.my.cnf` I added this

```
[client_visidata]
pager = pspg -X --quit-if-one-screen
```

Then use the `--default-group-suffix` on mycli.

In my `.bash_alias` I just added this `alias m='mycli --defaults-group-suffix="_visidata"'.` This basically call the `[client_visidata]` contents while using the mycli client. While the `mysqldump` wont read it, so it wont rise any error.